# How to edit order templates in Magento?

Tags: html, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I want to edit this HTML page `index.php/sales/order/view/order_id/565`. Anyone can tell me from where I can edit the HTML that I want to change the 2 labels only from HTML page.

Comment: I've tried to improve your title with a specific question - titles are not for explaining how new you are to something, or asking for `help please` - make it useful, if only to avoid downvotes. If it can be made more specific still, please edit it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These order template files can be find under below folder,

```
frontend/yourtemplatefolder/default/template/sales/
```

I am listing some of files from it,

```
frontend/yourtemplatefolder/default/template/sales/order/info.phtml
frontend/yourtemplatefolder/default/template/sales/order/view.phtml
frontend/yourtemplatefolder/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml
frontend/yourtemplatefolder/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

So, please go to your custom design template folder and then search for above files. As per your requirement you can try to edit those. Also if above files are not available in your custom template, then copy from core folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the labels on html page, you should make changes in template file(.phtml). To find the template file which renders the output, turn on template path hints.In admin panel navigate to

> system->configuration->developer->->debug->template path hints

Select the store view and turn on. Now reload the page and see the path of template file which is used to render those 2 labels. If path is from your theme, you can modify those labels there, either copy same directory structure in your new theme and make modifications there.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow few step to make changes in order template.
Go to your theme folder and create Magento_Sales folder and copy below files from vendor/magento/module-sales folder.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/templates/sales/order/info.phtml
vendor/magento/module-sales/templates/sales/order/view.phtml
vendor/magento/module-sales/templates/sales/order/items.phtml
vendor/magento/module-sales/templates/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

and paste in below theme Magento_Sales directory

```
 /templates/sales/order/info.phtml
 /templates/sales/order/view.phtml
 /templates/sales/order/items.phtml
 /templates/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

Now you can make changes in these files for modification in order template.